# Utilização correta do async and await no Asp.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, async

Estou criando um método assincrono para envio de Emails a partir da abertura ou alteração do objeto, porem ao chamar o método de envio de email tenho que colocar o await na frente e o retorno do método tem que ser async Task, porem ao fazer isso no controller da minha aplicação tenho que chamar o método também com await na frente e colocar o retorno da action async Task

Gostaria de saber se é dessa forma é a ideal para o uso do método assincrono.

Comment: O que você já fez? Mostre onde está tendo problema.

Comment: Vou colocar o código, mas não está apresentando problemas, apenas queria saber se a forma que fiz, que no final o retorno de ActionResult vira Task<ActionResult> está correto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, quando se usa async I/O, todos os métodos desse ponto até ao controlador têm de retornar uma `Task` ou `Task<T>`. Customa-se dizer "async all the way", que é codigo para "não mistures código async com código bloqueante".

Não precisam necessariamente da keyword `async`, apenas de retornar uma task.

A execução da acção vai ser mais ou menos assim:

- A request chega e o controlador é invocado
- As várias camadas do serviço são invocadas ate atingir o ponto em que o e-mail é enviado usando async I/O
- Este método retorna uma task
- Todos os outros métodos retornam também uma task, incluindo a acção do controlador
- A framework põe essa task de lado, e a thread fica livre para servir novas requests
- Quando a task completar (ou seja, quando o e-mail for enviado), a continuação da task (todo o código que vem depois do `await`) vai ser executada por uma thread da threadpool.

Veja os seguintes posts do Stephen Cleary:

- [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)
- [Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento dcastro