# Qual diferença entre ToListAsync() e ToList()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, async

Qual diferença entre `ToListAsync()` e `ToList()`?

Como no exemplo abaixo, qual a diferença entre um e outro?

```
using Modelo.Classes.Contexto;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace AppConsoleTestes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new dbContexto())
            {
                var ListaUsuario1 = await ctx.Usuarios.ToListAsync();
                var ListaUsuario2 = ctx.Usuarios.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ToListAsync()` é o `ToList` assíncrono. Métodos assíncronos podem ser executados sem travar a linha de execução principal da aplicação. Ex.: numa aplicação WinForms, não travar a GUI em operações longas.

Para o método ser executado assincronamente deve ser chamado com [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) antes dele e o método que o chama precisa estar marcado como [`async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh156513.aspx).

Se for usado da forma que mostra a pergunta, ele vai retornar um `Task<T>` e você vai ter que se preocupar em como resolvê-lo. Se usar `await ctx.Usuarios.ToListAsync()` o trabalho de "resolver" este `Task<T>` será automático.

---

Não vou dar mais detalhes sobre o uso de `async`/`await` porque já tem bastante sobre isso no site.

[Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2793/em-c-para-que-serve-a-palavra-chave-await?s=2|0.0000)

[Utilização correta do async and await no Asp.Net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-correta-do-async-and-await-no-asp-net)

Comment: Droga, estava terminando de escrever :(

Comment: Pode postar, não tem nada a perder, bem pelo contrário, se a resposta estiver certa, meu upvote é garantido. Essa pergunta vai servir pra mais gente no futuro, é bom termos várias respostas, desde que todas estejam corretas e nenhuma seja cópia da outra.

Answer (score 2):

O método com `Async` no nome é assíncrono, ou seja, ele tem capacidade de ser executado sem travar a linha de execução atual, então se ele tivesse sido chamado da forma correta logo após seu início o código já poderia partir para a próxima linha, e provavelmente o `ToListAsync()` executaria em paralelo.

Para que a assincronicidade ocorra de fato precisaria de um [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Existem diversos métodos com 'async' no nome, indicando que o mesmo é assincrono.
Porém como foi dito, é necessário utilizar as keywords async/await em conjunto.

Tu mesmo pode criar seus métodos asyncronos, e por padrão utilize no nome do método a palavra 'async', é uma boa prática. Pesquise pois existe muito artigo sobre isso.